# Labels placement in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I need all labels to be placed outside of the boundary (polyline features).  Most of the labels are placed outside the boundary line, while others (marked with red color) are placed inside the boundary.

What is the best way place all labels on the outside of the polyline?

[image: Label Placement]

Comment: Is that a polygon or polyline feature class?

Comment: All are polylines and points

Comment: Can you build or otherwise create a polygon for area 1?  If so then you could display it without color but give it a high feature weight to attempt to force labels off of it.  Maplex "Best" would probably do that better than the standard labeling engine.  If that fails you might convert to annotation and edit the problem ones.

Comment: Are you storing your data as shapefiles or geodatabase?

Comment: I have stored as Shape files

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution may be to convert to graphics and manually re-position the offending labels.

Comment: I have tried all above suggestions but still labels are inside. Manually is possible but i have to do this more than 3000 layouts...is there any alternative methods..

Answer (score 1):

[Convert your polylines to a polygon](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35321) and then adjust the label placement properties to 'Outside the Feature'.